# How to make a conditionally recursive function return (null) in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have a conditionally recursive function in ReactJS that I need to `return (null)` instead of `<></>` when no conditions are satisfied.

So I am quite new to ReactJS and I created this recursive function that loops over an array of arbitrary dimensions and creates these `<ViewCard>`'s as seen in the code below. It works fine, however when there is an empty array `[]`, which must occur sometimes, the function returns `<></>`, and I need it to instead return (null) or equal to null. Can I do that somehow? Would also be nice to know how I should handle the `key` attribute for the created children to avoid warnings/error in console.

A suiteable solution would be if I could remove the `<></>` wrapper around the `list.map()` expression. To just return the conditional output. But as I understand that is impossible due to syntax?

```js
function Split({ list, selectedfunc, key }) {
  
  return (
    <> 
      {list.map((item) => {
        return (
          <>
            {isInt(item[0]) && (
              <ViewCard id={item[0]} color="red" selectedfunc={selectedfunc} />
            )}

            {Array.isArray(item[0]) && (
              <Split list={item} selectedfunc={selectedfunc} />
            )}
          </>
       );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Also, if this recursive solution is bad practice, let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add an if clause

```
if (list.length === 0) {
   return null
}

// the rest of your large return
```

having said that, AFAIK there's no perceived difference for the user to return `null` or a Fragment, as none of them render anything to the DOM.

by the way, your `Fragment` should have a key, so better use

```
return (
    <> 
      {list.map((item) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
            {isInt(item[0]) && (
              <ViewCard key={<some-unique-id>} id={item[0]} color="red" selectedfunc={selectedfunc} />
            )}

            {Array.isArray(item[0]) && (
              <Split key={<some-unique-id>} list={item} selectedfunc={selectedfunc} />
            )}
          </React.Fragment>
       );
      })}
    </>
  );
```

replace `<some-unique-id>` with a unique identifier for each element. It does not have to be unique across the whole page, just unique across its siblings. Worst case scenario, you can rely on the `index` of the iteration (last resort). [Further info](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Comment: Hmm, intresting! Then there is probably something else that isn't working. I'll take a look at it tonight. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: you're welcome! I added one update about the missing keys (Which might cause unexpected renderings)

Comment: Hi again!  Had to replace <></> with <React.Fragment key={i}> in order to fix my unexpected renderings due to none unique keys among children as you mentioned and everything worked.

Comment: you're right ! I forgot about the keys. Thanks for noticing it - I updated my answer!